# Viewing Logcat with Android app in Chrome using ARC Welder

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-arc

I am trying to get our Android app to run under Chrome using ARC Welder on a Mac.  The app is crashing soon after startup and I'm trying to look at the Logcat to see what is going on.  I have found the following instructions in another thread that discusses how to do this.

1. Open your debug APK in ARC Welder and run it
2. Open logcat in Android Studio, (or what ever tool you normally use to view logcat).
3. Open Chrome and type "chrome://inspect/#apps" in the address bar
4. Hopefully you see your App name listed, click the 'inspect' link for your app.
5. In the Javascript Console that appears type "plugin.shell('adbd')" and press enter.
6. Now go back to Android Studio and you should see a load of log messages in the logcat, filter by your app name and hopefully you are good to go.

My problem is after step #3 I don't see my app listed when going to "chrome://inspect/#apps". I only see the ARC Welder app listed (and sometimes even that is not there). Hence there is no "inspect" link to click.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  How can I view the app's Logcat when running under ARC Welder?

Answer (score 0):

I did finally get this figured out.  The app appears on the chrome://extensions page and it is there that I can "inspect" it.  It also appears that you can only do a plugin.shell('logcat') while the app is actually running.  So if the app is crashing at startup, you need to put a delay in so you can enter this command before the crash actually happens.